# Populating the "Now Playing" screen on watchOS 6

Tags: watchkit, avaudiosession, watchos-6

I'm trying to display the currently playing audio from my app in the watches `Now Playing` app.

I'm streaming the audio using the `AVPlayer` and set the `AVAudioSession` category and activated the session.

I've also tried to use the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` without any luck.

Is there another way to provide this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And just as I hit post I figured it out!

You also have to setup the `MPRemoteCommandCenter`. ‍♂️

Leaving this here for future reference.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you - been struggling with this for a few days now ...

Comment: May I ask what did you set up with MPRemoteCommandCenter ? The watch seems to show the titles I send it but not the artwork for some reason. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

Please show some code for reference, but `MvNowPlayingInfoCentre` should work fine.
Take a look at this for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41686834/12149235